# Count occurrences in any order

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Imagine I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(
  name1 = c("John", "Jake", "Ann", "Mary", "Harry"),
  name2 = c("Jake", "John", "Mary", "Ann", "Mary"),
  value = c(2, 4, 6, 8, 10)
)
```

I want to create a new data frame that sums `value` over any rows where `name1` and `name2` and the same regardless of their order.  So my result would be:

```
result <- data.frame(
  name1 = c("John", "Ann", "Harry"),
  name2 = c("Jake", "Mary", "Mary"),
  value = c(6, 14, 10) 
)
```

Any clever ideas, preferably using tidyverse?  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `pmin` and `pmax` which sorts the data alphabetically and take `sum` of the `value`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(nam1 = pmin(name1, name2), nam2 = pmax(name1, name2)) %>%
  summarise(value = sum(value), .groups = 'drop')

#  nam1  nam2  value
#  <chr> <chr> <dbl>
#1 Ann   Mary     14
#2 Harry Mary     10
#3 Jake  John      6
```

Answer (score 2):

An option with `igraph` package

```
library(igraph)

get.data.frame(
  simplify(
    graph_from_data_frame(df, directed = FALSE),
    edge.attr.comb = sum
  )
)
```

gives

```
  from    to value
1 John  Jake     6
2  Ann  Mary    14
3 Mary Harry    10
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[,.(value = sum(value)), by = .(nam1 = pmin(name1, name2), nam2 = pmax(name1, name2))]
```